# Generar numero de radicado SQL

Tags: sql-server

Me encuentro con la necesidad de generar un código por cada registro que se inserte en la base de datos y agregarlo al campo NumeroRadicado, he buscado documentación pero la única que encuentro es el autoincremental del identity pero el código debe llevar concatenado las letras AG; entonces el autoincremental no funcionaria, tienen alguna idea de como se puede realizar?

Muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PRC_PRUEBA_INSERTAR]
@idRadicado int output,
@NumeroRadicado varchar (50),
@Documento varchar (100),
@TipoSoporte varchar (50),
@Remitente varchar (100),
@AsuntoFactura varchar (100),
@Destinatario varchar (100),
@Observaciones varchar (254),
@DesOpcional varchar (100)
AS
INSERT INTO tblDocumentalP ( 
       [NumeroRadicado]
      ,[Fecha]
      ,[Documento]
      ,[TipoSoporte]
      ,[Remitente]
      ,[AsuntoFactura]
      ,[Destinatario]
      ,[Observaciones]
      ,[DesOpcional])
      VALUES 
      (@NumeroRadicado, 
      SYSDATETIME(), 
      @Documento, 
      @TipoSoporte, 
      @Remitente, 
      @AsuntoFactura, 
      @Destinatario,
      @Observaciones,
      @DesOpcional)
```

Comment: Podrías generar una columna que combine `AG` con el autoincremental, el único tema con los `identity`  es si te preocupa que existan "huecos" de numéración.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no tienes problemas con eventuales huecos en la numeración, creo que lo más simple, si tienes al menos SQL Server 2008, es crear una [columna calculada](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-computed-column-definition-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
CREATE TABLE #Ejemplo (
    ID              INT IDENTITY,
    NumeroRadicado  AS ('AG' + RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 15) + CONVERT(VARCHAR, ID),15)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    Dato            VARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO #Ejemplo (Dato) VALUES ('Dato1') , ('Dato2')

SELECT  *
    FROM #Ejemplo
```

Salida:

```
╔══════╦═══════════════════╦═══════╗
║ ID   ║ NumeroRadicado    ║ Dato  ║
╠══════╬═══════════════════╬═══════╣
║ 1,00 ║ AG000000000000001 ║ Dato1 ║
╠══════╬═══════════════════╬═══════╣
║ 2,00 ║ AG000000000000002 ║ Dato2 ║
╚══════╩═══════════════════╩═══════╝
```

Notas:

- Como verás combinamos un `IDENTITY` con la cadena fija `AG`, el padding de `0` es opcional pero útil ya que unifica el criterio de ordenamiento
- Importante: las columnas calculadas por defecto no existen físicamente, por lo que no sirven para ser usadas como índices, a menos que las materialices mediante `PERSISTED NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que se me ocurre rápidamente(y no se si sea lo mas optimo), es que vayas y veas el máximo valor de tu tabla y en base a ese le agregues un +1, el problema es que si eliminas un registro, va a quedar ese hueco, pero esto debería funcionarte en base a lo que necesitas.

Habra que mejorarlo, solo es una idea

Creas estos valores antes de tu insert, y al final en el insert le pones el @Valor1 o como lo gustes llamar, pero antes se valida que tu tabla no este vacia, y siempre obtiene el numero mas grande que exista en tu tabla, así nunca se va a repetir.

```
DECLARE @Valor1 VARCHAR(MAX),
        @Valor2 INT

    SET @Valor1 = (SELECT COUNT('') FROM tblDocumentalP)

    IF @Valor1 = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @Valor1 = (
                SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @Valor1 + 1) + 'AG'
                )
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @Valor2 = (
                SELECT MAX(CONVERT(INT, REPLACE(NumeroRadicado, 'AG', '')))
                FROM tblDocumentalP
                )
        SET @Valor1 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @Valor2 + 1) + 'AG'
    END
```

Espero y te sirva, saludos.